# jQuery, make .click() which is within the last else statement, run the first if statement?

Tags: jquery

Is it some how possible, to make the `$sliderPane.click();` which is located in the last `else` statement, run the first `if` statement?

Any clever ideas would be great thanks.

```
$tabTwitter.on('click', function () {

    if ( twitterOpen == true ) {

        twitterOpen = false;
        $panelTwitter.fadeOut(500); 

        $sliderPane.animate({
            "left" : 0
        }, 500, function() {
            $sliderPane.removeAttr('style');                     
        });

    } else if ( facebookOpen == true ) {

        facebookOpen = false;
        $panelFacebook.fadeOut(500); 

        twitterOpen = true;
        $panelTwitter.fadeIn(500);

    } else {

        twitterOpen = true;
        $panelTwitter.fadeIn(500);

        $sliderPane.css({
            "left":0,"cursor":"pointer"
        }).animate({
            "left" : "-490px"
        }, 500, function() {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: headerHeight - 69
            }, 800);
            return false;
        }).click();                 

    }

});
```

Comment: Doesn't it work as expected now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var clickHandler = function () {

    if ( twitterOpen == true ) {

        twitterOpen = false;
        $panelTwitter.fadeOut(500); 

        $sliderPane.animate({
            "left" : 0
        }, 500, function() {
            $sliderPane.removeAttr('style');                     
        });

    } else if ( facebookOpen == true ) {

        facebookOpen = false;
        $panelFacebook.fadeOut(500); 

        twitterOpen = true;
        $panelTwitter.fadeIn(500);

    } else {

        twitterOpen = true;
        $panelTwitter.fadeIn(500);

        $sliderPane.css({
            "left":0,"cursor":"pointer"
        }).animate({
            "left" : "-490px"
        }, 500, function() {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: headerHeight - 69
            }, 800);
            return false;
        }).click(clickHandler);                 

    }

};

$tabTwitter.on('click', clickHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could alway try to use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) since the 'if' is the very first statement in your code block.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure that will work. Won't trigger just run it without a click?

Comment: You should be able to actually trigger the click event on the element.  Similar to the demo on the trigger page.

Answer (score 0):

Separate into named functions. Call first if function. Done.

Comment: would you put them into functions out side of this script, or where they are inside the statements?